# Encode & Post Image via Command Line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal

I have a Rails app that has a Picture model using the carrier-wave gem to handle image upload/saving.

Eventually, I plan to have an iOS app POST an image to the Picture model's controller / create action.

Before that, I'd like to test some things locally and simulate the POST event.

Can I do this by encoding/posting via OSX Terminal?  I imagine I need to encode the image file into (binary?) and POST it to the controller/action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to simulate this is using the command line utility `curl`. You can do something like:

```
curl -X POST -F field1=value1 -F file=@path/to/file.jpg http://example.org/pictures
```

The `-F` options allow you to set form field values. For example, your controller might be expecting that a couple form fields will be submitted with the file upload. You can pass in multiple `-F name=value` options. If the `value` starts with a `@`, then `curl` will read from a file (such as the image you want to upload).

The `-X POST` makes curl run a POST request to the server. I'm not 100% sure it is necessary, because I think `curl` will automatically switch to POST since you've included a file with the upload... but it won't hurt anything either.

`curl` is a very powerful tool. You can get additional information by typing `man curl` in your OSX Terminal window. It has a lot of options and can handle just about any situation you throw at it.

Comment: Perfect, I've used curl for many other things, but didn't think to check its documentation to see if it could handle files directly -- thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @DanShev! Could you mark my answer as accepted so I can get some delicious points? =) Thanks!